# How can I have a UIView act like bounds to a CaLayer?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

I have a bezier path which I am converting into CALayer and then adding to a view.

I want to have the UIView height and width that of exactly CALayer shape.

```
myHTML = @"<html><body><svg height= \"400\" width= \"400\"><g><path d=\"M 20 20  C 30 30 40 40 50 50 M 50 50 C 60 70 80 70 60 50 \"  transform=\"translate(-20, -20)\" stroke = \"#000000\" fill=\"none\" stroke-width=\"5px\"></path></g></svg></body></html>";

    NSArray *test = [SVGBezierPath pathsFromSVGString:myHTML];
    for(SVGBezierPath *path in test) {
        // Create a layer for each path
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.path = path.CGPath;
        UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        // Set its display properties
        layer.lineWidth   = 4;
        layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        layer.fillColor   = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        vw.center = self.view.center;
        [vw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        // Add it to the layer hierarchy
        [vw.layer addSublayer:layer];

        [self.view addSubview:vw];
    }
```

When I try this code I am getting this
[image]

I tried giving view the width and height of layer

```
vw = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(vw.bounds.origin.x, vw.bounds.origin.y, layer.bounds.size.height, layer.bounds.size.width)];
```

Then the view disappears and only the layer is visible.

I want to get something like the image below, I have the code for the resize view and thing, but need to get the bounds of view to be exactly the max height and max width of the view just like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view frame to the paths bounding box instead. Assuming that SVGBezierPath is a sub-class of UIBezierPath.

```
// First create your UIView vw
vw.bounds = CGRectMake(vw.bounds.origin.x, vw.bounds.origin.y,
                       path.bounds.size.width, path.bounds.size.height)];
```

Comment: The view now is way smaller and the CAShapeLayer is half cut

Comment: Sorry, the width and height were mixed up. Please try again!